# Why is there a limit on the eval function?

Tags: python, eval

Why does an error occur in this code when the number of range increases?
He's working at 92, and you can't bet any more.

```
import random
from random import randint
masz = []
pmasz = '('
n = 0
for i in range(92):    
    masz.append(str(randint(-10000, +10000)))   
    masz.append(random.choice(['+', '-', '*', '/'])) 
    pmasz += masz[n] +")" + masz[n+1]
    n += 2 
print(eval((n//2-1)*"("+pmasz[:-1]))
```

Comment: The python AST compiler has some limitations on stack depth. I'm guessing you're running into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to overly deep parentheses nesting.  This is a known issue that probably won't be fixed.
You can read the details [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue3971).

You can avoid the problem by evaluating intermediate results to limit the nesting depth.

I also suggest using `ast.literal_eval`, which is safer then using `eval`.